# Как работать с переключателями для виджета TreeView в MonoDevelop?

Tags: c#, checkbox, mono, monodevelop, treeview

Доброго дня, уважаемые гуру разработки.
Пишу небольшой менеджер задач и пытаюсь использовать для этого MonoDevelop.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать работу с переключателями(check box) в Mono?
 По документации на сайте нашел как можно создать сворачиваемые списки для TreeView. В документации указано, что ячейку TreeView можно отрендерить как CellRendererToggle (Used to display a check box), но больше никаких описаний по работе с этим типом не могу найти.
 Хочу реализовать возможность устанавливать и сбрасывать статус переключателя и дальше менять данные в модели. Сейчас получилось лишь выводить столбик переключателей, но поменять их статус не знаю как
полный код проекта лежит на https://github.com/veitsi/todonet
Сейчас список задач формирую так:

```
 private void TreeInit ()
    {
    Gtk.TreeViewColumn taskColumn = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn ();
    taskColumn.Title = "Task description";
    Gtk.CellRendererText taskTextCell = new Gtk.CellRendererText ();
    taskColumn.PackStart (taskTextCell, true);

    Gtk.TreeViewColumn statusColumn = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn ();
    statusColumn.Title = "status";
    Gtk.CellRendererToggle statusCell = new Gtk.CellRendererToggle ();
    statusColumn.PackStart (statusCell, true);

    tree.AppendColumn (taskColumn);
    tree.AppendColumn (statusColumn);
    taskColumn.AddAttribute (taskTextCell, "text", 0);
    statusColumn.AddAttribute (statusCell, "text", 1);
}

public void TreeBuild (ToDoList todo)
{
    //textview.Buffer.Text = "Загрузили список задач\n";
    this.TreeInit ();

    Gtk.TreeStore todoListStore = new Gtk.TreeStore (typeof(string), typeof(string));
    Gtk.TreeIter iter;
    foreach (Task t in todo.tasks) {
        iter=todoListStore.AppendValues (t.text);
        if (t.subs.Count > 0) {
            foreach (SubTask s in t.subs)
                todoListStore.AppendValues (iter, s.text, "");
        }
    }

    tree.Model = todoListStore;
}
```